# Removing complete lines of text in a text file (on Python)

Tags: python, file, text

I am working with an output log file that has 12 thousand lines of code, most of which include something that looks like this:

```
"760.0132   EXP     window1: blendMode = 'avg'"
```

My goal is to entirely remove any line that has "EXP    window1: blendMode = 'avg'". I can remove that text bit from all of the lines where it is found, but not the number. This is the code I have used to delete the text bits (borrowed from another stack overflow question/answer):

```
infile = "01_Day1_run1.txt"
outfile = "01_Day1_run1_cleaned.txt"

delete_list = ["    EXP     window1: blendMode = 'avg'"]

fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
for word in delete_list:
    line = line.replace(word, "")
fout.write(line)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

I was hoping that I would be able to add something like

```
delete_list = ["1**.****    EXP     window1: blendMode = 'avg'"]
```

in order to delete any number that includes all of the text, and also any number in that line, but it does not seem to work. Any advice on how to best clean up the log file would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much,
Simon

Comment: do you want to actually remove the line or just replace a matched line with a blank line?

Comment: also your indentation seems to be off - should your `for word in delete_list` loop be indented over one?

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = "01_Day1_run1.txt"
outfile = "01_Day1_run1_cleaned.txt"

delete_list = ["    EXP     window1: blendMode = 'avg'"]

fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "a")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        if word in line:
            wordCheck = False
            break
        else:
            wordCheck = True
    if wordCheck:
        fout.write(line)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Maybe cleaner:

```
with open("01_Day1_run1.txt", "r") as infile, open("01_Day1_run1_cleaned.txt", "a") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not any(filter in line for filter in delete_list ):
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = "01_Day1_run1.txt"
outfile = "01_Day1_run1_cleaned.txt"

delete_string = "EXP     window1: blendMode = 'avg'"

fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "a")
for line in fin.readLines():
    if delete_list not in line:
        fout.write(line)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this using Python? You can do this with a simple `grep -v` or `findstr /V`, as in following example:

```
Prompt>grep -v "blendmode" input.txt >output.txt
```